# Pyspark: groupby and then count true values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

My data structure is in JSON format:

```
"header"{"studentId":"1234","time":"2016-06-23","homeworkSubmitted":True}
"header"{"studentId":"1234","time":"2016-06-24","homeworkSubmitted":True}
"header"{"studentId":"1234","time":"2016-06-25","homeworkSubmitted":True}
"header"{"studentId":"1236","time":"2016-06-23","homeworkSubmitted":False}
"header"{"studentId":"1236","time":"2016-06-24","homeworkSubmitted":True}
....
```

I need to plot a histogram that shows number of homeworkSubmitted: True over all stidentIds. I wrote code that flattens the data structure, so my keys are header.studentId, header.time and header.homeworkSubmitted.

I used keyBy to group by studentId:

```
    initialRDD.keyBy(lambda row: row['header.studentId'])
              .map(lambda (k,v): (k,v['header.homeworkSubmitted']))
              .map(mapTF).groupByKey().mapValues(lambda x: Counter(x)).collect()
```

This gives me result like this:

```
("1234", Counter({0:0, 1:3}),
("1236", Counter(0:1, 1:1))
```

I need only number of counts of 1, possibly mapped to a list so that I can plot a histogram using matplotlib. I am not sure how to proceed and filter everything.

Edit: at the end I iterated through the dictionary and added counts to a list and then plotted histogram of the list. I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to do the whole process I outlined in my code.

Comment: Note it is not valid JSON if there is a `"header"` or `True` instead of `true`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
df = sqlContext.read.json('/path/to/your/dataset/')
df.filter(df.homeworkSubmitted == True).groupby(df.studentId).count()
```

Note it is not valid JSON if there is a `"header"` or `True` instead of `true`

Comment: come to this answer, but I don't think this is complete. It will lose groups with no True values.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Spark in front of me right now, though I can edit this tomorrow when I do.

But if I'm understanding this you have three key-value RDDs, and need to filter by homeworkSubmitted=True. I would think you turn this into a dataframe, then use:

```
df.where(df.homeworkSubmitted==True).count()
```

You could then use group by operations if you wanted to explore subsets based on the other columns.

Comment: No, this doesn't work. PipelineRDD object has no attribute 'where'

Comment: Yes, you can only use 'where' on a dataframe. That's why you have to convert your RDDs first.

Comment: Not sure what isn't liked about this answer.  Your json data is already in a relational format and ideally suited for a dataframe.  Simply load it into a dataframe and use .where() and you'll not only have your counts, you'll have the ability to analyze results based on time submitted as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the false, keeping it in RDD, then count the True with counter

```
initialRDD.filter(lambda row : row['header.homeworkSubmitted'])
```

Another solution would be to sum the booleans

```
data = sc.parallelize([('id1',True),('id1',True),
                    ('id2',False),
                    ('id2',False),('id3',False),('id3',True) ])


data.reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y).collect()
```

Outputs

```
[('id2', 0), ('id3', 1), ('id1', 2)]
```